# How does predictive model for the Eurovision Song Contest work?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, predictive-models, markov-process, monte-carlo

I've encountered interesting prediction of  Eurovision Song Contest http://mewo2.com/nerdery/2013/05/12/eurovision-2013-first-predictions/ it based on some kind of Bayesian model I assume but I don't understand how it works (the description is too sketchy for me).

Along the lines it says that it uses Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampler but what exactly does it sample?

Comment: I don't know how helpful this is but the code and data are apparently available at https://github.com/mewo2/eurovision

Comment: @GaëlLaurans thank you. I don't speak R, yet but will definitely try to understand the code although whitepaper on similar topic would be better.